# How to init UIButton's type after using alloc?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I know we can use the `buttonWithType` method to get an UIButton with specific type.

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)];
```

Today, I casually use UIButton's alloc/init method to create an UIButton:

```
UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 100, 50)];
```

then I found there is no way to change the button's type.Because the UIButton's buttonType property is readonly.

In UIKit.framework, UIButton.h :

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIButtonType buttonType;
```

My question is:if I use alloc/init to create a UIButton, can I change the UIButton's type? If not, since there is **NOT** any init method like `-initWithType` in UIButton, we can only use the `+buttonWithType` method to get an autorelease UIButton. It sounds a little strange, why not provide an initWithType method?

Comment: Why not create the button with initWithType: first and then change his frame?

Comment: @Mat Hi, the `initWithType` method is NOT exist in UIButton.

Comment: sorry, i meant buttonWithType:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why even have to alloc and init if +buttonWithType handles that for you?  Just reverse your thinking like this:

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 100, 50)];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I usually use `buttonWithType`. Today I just casually found this problem, so I want to know if there is any design purpose or not.

Comment: I imagine it's because they don't have a sure fire way of switching the button's type yet.

Comment: I think your imagine is reasonable. Thanks, I just want to make sure it.